# when use strlen to get the length of a const char* , I get a negative number?

Tags: c, linux

**Problem solved, I missed a `+1` when `malloc`**

I am doing something on fuse, and I got a `SIGABRT` here, and then I use `gdb` to track that, I found something odd. I get a negative strlen result. I think that's why when I `free` my `char*`, I got this signal.(sprintf may write more bytes then we `malloc`, so if I `malloc` a very small number, it still could write things in, but when I free that, the problem comes)

The function is here, the arguments are provided by fuse(A use space filesystem).

```
static int fs_getattr(const char *path, struct stat *stbuf)

    {
        int res;
        char *fullpath = NULL;
        fullpath = malloc(cpflen+strlen(path));
        sprintf(fullpath, "%s%s", cachepathfix, path);  
        res = lstat(fullpath, stbuf);
        free(fullpath);
    }
```

I ran gdb to see what's going on there, at first I thought that may be due to the `const char *` do not ended by `\000`, but it actually ended by this

```
(gdb) x/10c path
0x8937140:  47 '/'  116 't' 101 'e' 115 's' 116 't' 0 '\000'
```

And then I try `p strlen(path)`, I got a wired number `-1218664720`

```
(gdb) p strlen(path)
$2 = -1218664720
```

Is that I could not use `strlen` to measure the length of a `const char *` or other things I've done is wrong? Thanks you guys.

Comment: Is `cpflen` the length of `cachepathfix`?

Comment: You have an off-by-one error in your `malloc()`: you don't account for the final 0. It should malloc for `cpflen + strlen(path) + 1`

Comment: I haven't used `gdb` for a while, but does `p strlen(path)` actually *call* the function (as opposed to, say, printing out its address)?

Comment: It might be worth putting the strlen into a local variable, and checking it isn't some gdb weirdness. Also you could add `assert` to check that path is not NULL, and that strlen(path) is >= 0.

Comment: @hmjd yes, it is. @aix when I try this `(gdb) p *(int *)strlen(path)` I got also an impossible result `$2 = 2089506646` @fge I'll try that, I have lots of other codes in this c file which do not have this `+1`.

Comment: @aix yes, gdb actually arranges for a function call. There is just one common annoyance in glibc-gdb, and that is `p strerror(somenumber)` which gives <weird value>, since it seems something does not know that strerror returns a char*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add enough space for terminating null character in `fullpath`.

Change:

```
fullpath = malloc(cpflen+strlen(path));
```

to:

```
fullpath = malloc(sizeof(char) * (cpflen + strlen(path) + 1));
```